# Geocoder function is not working

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I have using google api for fetching location address from lat and long.That was running good but today this message suddenly occur..
    I have done

```
geocoder = new Geocoder(MapNavigation.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);

HTTP request blocked due to automatic backoff: https://www.google.com/loc/m/api
Blocked by temporary_blocked2: https://www.google.com/loc/m/api
com.google.android.gms.http.a: Blocked by rule: temporary_blocked2
```

Comment: Please reply any one!!!!!!

Comment: This seems to happen occasionally: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2q6pgq/timeout_problems_with_the_builtin_geocoder/ - try again in a few hours. Moreover, make sure you're not exceeding the API's quota.

Comment: Thanks Tom,But kindly tell me what is API quota

Comment: 10 request per second, 2500 per day: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

Answer (score 2):

Happening with us too. Created following bug for Geocoder team:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9153

Answer (score 0):

Happening with us too. And onLocationChanged of google service also does not work :-(.

Answer (score 0):

Using below code I'm able to get location without using **Google-API** but it is not working for **OnePlus** devices.
Tested with internet.
Any one has idea about this issue please reply.

```
if (Geocoder.isPresent())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(contex, Locale.getDefault());
                            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                            if (addresses.size() > 0)
                            {
                                fullAddress = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                                addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
                                street=addresses.get(0).getPremises()+","+addresses.get(0).getFeatureName()+","+addresses.get(0).getSubLocality()+","+addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                                locality = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
                                city = addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
                                state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                                country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ignored)
                        {
                            // after a while, Geocoder start to trhow "Service not availalbe" exception. really weird since it was working before (same device, same Android version etc..
                        }
                    }
```