# Google Place Picker unable to get location - Temporary blocked exception

Tags: android, google-places-api, temporary, blocked

From time to time, I keep getting following error code when trying to use Place Picker widget from Google:

> e.android.gms.persistent W/Places: ?: onFailure StatusCode: 13, Cause:
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException 05-24 14:11:44.969
>   2166-2749/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/Volley: [126]
>   BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for
>   https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/searchByChain?key=...

And then:

> .android.gms.persistent W/GCM.HTTP: HTTP request blocked due to
>   automatic backoff:
>   https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/getPlaceById?key=... 05-24
>   14:11:51.395 2593-2859/com.google.android.gms W/GoogleURLConnFactory:
>   Blocked by temporary_blocked2:

And this:

> e.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/RequestManagerImpl: Producing
>   location failed
>                                                                                                     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
>                                                                                                         at b.b.b.get(SourceFile:116)
>                                                                                                         at com.google.android.apps.gsa.extradex.kato.d.l.a(SourceFile:1154)
>                                                                                                         at com.google.android.apps.gsa.extradex.kato.d.p.n(SourceFile:75)
>                                                                                                         at com.google.android.apps.gsa.extradex.kato.d.p.aE(SourceFile:19)
>                                                                                                         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.p.N(SourceFile:2209)
>                                                                                                         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.o.run(SourceFile:128)
>                                                                                                         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bh$1$1.run(SourceFile:988)
>                                                                                                         at com.google.android.apps.gsa.taskgraph.b.a.l.run(SourceFile:66)
>                                                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>                                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                                         at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
>                                                                                                         at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
>                                                                                                         at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
>                                                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                                                                         at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
>                                                                                                      Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was
>   cancelled.

All neccesay api is enabled in Google console. Place picker actually works, but unable to find any place or address. It seems to be temporary, after some time it starts working again.

I'm confused, are there some limits for geolocation api from Google? I am unable to find any information and I'm pretty sure my app should not exceed any limits, because it's not even available public yet.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a known bug. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828055 and [Geocoder function is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806065/geocoder-function-is-not-working) have more info.

Answer (score 0):

Well, answer found, there are the limits: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage

> Google Places API Web Service enforces a default limit of 1,000 free
>   requests per 24 hour period, calculated as the sum of client-side and
>   server-side requests. If your app exceeds the initial limit, the app
>   will start failing.

But I wonder how my app exceeded that limit.